# Record file audio from URL using Java

Tags: java, audio-streaming

I'm trying to do a simple script, which it allows to record a file (.wav) from a URL. Im using Java Sound API to do that but I didnt find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
try{
        URLConnection conn = new URL("http://play.cadenaser.com/").openConnection();
        InputStream audioSrc = conn.getInputStream();

        //add buffer for mark/reset support
        InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioSrc);
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

        OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.wav"));

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - t <= 5000) {
            AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outstream);
        }
        outstream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
```

If anyone could help me, I'd be grateful.ç
Thanks!

Comment: Is the URL http://play.cadenaser.com/ just an example? That URL did not seem to present any kind of audio stream when I tried it. Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the URI from the streaming I was looking for... I've already found a solution. Thanks for your helpness